# Why I have to turn off mobile data before pinging goes through on bluetooth network?

Tags: bluetooth, data

Android (Version11) phone has mobile data turned on, then it connects to another bluetooth device B which is a Bluetooth pand server.
After pairing and network service connection, B provides an IP to Android phone.

So android phone has mobile data and a new network interface with IP 192.168.44.2;  Device B has 192.168.44.1.

I can ping from Device B to android phone.
But when I ping from android phone to Device B, it can't get response, I have to TURN OFF mobile data first before it can ping B.

If android takes this new IP 192.168.44.2 and subnet 255.255.255.0, how can it fail to ping device B on the same 192.168.44.* subnet ?  Is this new network not in the routing table ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This might be caused by the same reason as you can't use Wifi and mobile data at the same time. The underlaying Linux system supports multiple network interfaces and specific routes but Android seem to follow the "one IP connection at a time" rule. There are multiple questions on that topic on this site.